# Pandas map to DataFrame from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I am currently mapping and renaming various string values to columns in `pandas` via this function:

```
df["fundbenchmark"] = df["name"].map(lambda x: "American Express" if "AXP" in x else "Apple" if "AAPL" in x else "Google" if "GOOG" in x else "")
```

I will however do this for several columns and for many different renamings. Here is another column with identical content, so it would be repetitive to add all companies there also.

```
df["subclass"] = df["name"].map(lambda x: "American Express" if "AXP" in x else "Apple" if "AAPL" in x else "Google" if "GOOG" in x else "")
```

As such I would like to maintain a dictionary like:

```
companies = {"AXP": "American Express", "AAPL": "Apple", "GOOG": "Google"}
```

and call that for all instances when I need to map company names. How can I make it `map`for matches in `companies` instead of `lambda x`?

---

Current DataFrame:

```
Name              
"BULL AXP UN X3 VON"
"BEAR AXP UN X3 VON"
"BULL GOOG UN X5 VON"
"BEAR GOOG UN X5 VON"
"BEAR ABC123 X2 CBZ"
```

Desired output:

```
Name                    Fundbenchmark             Subclass
"BULL AXP UN X3 VON"      "American Express"      "American Express"
"BEAR AXP UN X3 VON"      "American Express"      "American Express"
"BULL GOOG UN X5 VON"     "Google"                "Google"
"BEAR GOOG UN X5 VON"     "Google"                "Google"
"BEAR ABC123 X2 CBZ"      "BEAR ABC123 X2 CBZ"    "BEAR ABC123 X2 CBZ" #Not in Dictionary
```

Dictionary:

```
companies = {"AXP": "American Express", "GOOG": "Google"}
```

So if abbreviation exists in dictionary, then write that name to other columns.

Or, if the abbreviation is not in the dictionary, duplicate the whole cell.

Comment: @JohnE Sorry about that. I have edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: No worries, that's much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is the most elegant way, but it should do the trick:

```
df['fbm'] = df['name']
for i in companies:
    df.loc[ df.name.str.contains(i), 'fbm' ] = companies[i]

                  name                 fbm
0   BULL AXP UN X3 VON    American Express
1   BEAR AXP UN X3 VON    American Express
2  BULL GOOG UN X5 VON              Google
3  BEAR GOOG UN X5 VON              Google
4   BEAR ABC123 X2 CBZ  BEAR ABC123 X2 CBZ
```

One thing to keep in mind here is that because this is not a dictionary lookup, you could have more than one match.  For example, 'ABC' and 'UN' are both valid tickers and 'BEAR' is or was.  With this method, the last match will be kept and any prior matches discarded.

Comment: Thanks, will try this. `np.where` is imported from `numpy` correct?

Comment: @Winterflags -- yeah, np is numpy.  But actually I just replaced that line using `loc` instead of `np.where`, probably a more standard way to do it.  I think `str.contains(i)` is the real key there.  Beyond that there's a few different ways to do that line including `loc` and `np.where`

Comment: Thanks, that way I didn't have to import numpy also. This works now! Thanks so much for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`

```
Current DataFrame:

Name              
"BULL AXP UN X3 VON"
"BEAR AXP UN X3 VON"
"BULL GOOG UN X5 VON"
"BEAR GOOG UN X5 VON"
"BEAR ABC123 X2 CBZ"


companies = {"AXP": "American Express", "GOOG": "Google"}
```

we create a new column that extract the tickers from your column.

```
df['Tickers'] = df.Name.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

We then use map your dictionary `companies` to the tickers to create a column with the names of the ticker symbols:

```
df['Ticker_Name'] = df['Tickers'].map(companies)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Replace:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['string1','string2','string3'],
                 'B':['StringA','StringB','StringC']})
```

Creates:

```
             A        B
    0  string1  StringA
    1  string2  StringB
    2  string3  StringC
```

Then map your replacements in a dictionary:

```
to_replace = {'string1':'replace1','StringC':'replaceC'}
```

Then replace:

```
 df.replace(to_replace)
          A         B
0  replace1   StringA
1   string2   StringB
2   string3  replaceC
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This will replace all instances as defined by the dictionary, but it will not exclude the rest of the string as `.map(lambda x: "American Express" if "AXP" in x else ""`. Can I make replace discard the rest?

Comment: Try this:
df.applymap(lambda x: x if x in to_replace.keys() else '')

Comment: I think we're on the right path but I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'`.

Comment: Applymap is for the whole df, is you;re doing just a single column (series), then just use apply.

Comment: @JohnE Thanks for the suggestion. If I do your code for  `df["fundbenchmark"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: companies.get(x,x) )` it copies the whole column `"name"` to column "`fundbenchmark"` but no substitution occurs, also it does not discard the irrelevant bits as does my current non-dictionary solution `df["fundbenchmark"] = df["name"].map(lambda x: "American Express" if "AXP" in x else "")`

Comment: @LiamFoley `df["fundbenchmark"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: x if x in companies.keys() else "")` writes nothing at all. Using this dictionary: `companies = {"AXP": "American Express", "BIDU": "Baidu"}`